# Recognizing the User's Current Activity in Android

Tags: android

i am working with Recognizing the User's Current Activity from http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html

i used folow code to create new ActivityRecognitionClient:

```
public class GPSLocationService extends Service implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

private String TAG = "[ServiceDetect]";
//
private ActivityRecognitionClient mActivityRecognitionClient ;
private PendingIntent mPendingIntent ;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub




            if (checkGooglePlayAvaible()) {
                startTrack();
            }



    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // code detetc user acitivity here      
            getActivityRecognitionClient().requestActivityUpdates((2 * 60 * 1000), createPendingRequest());

}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    mActivityRecognitionClient = null;
    mPendingIntent.cancel();
    mPendingIntent = null;

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {

        try{
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult((Activity) this.getApplicationContext(), 0);

        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // it happens if the resolution intent has been canceled,
            // or is no longer able to execute the request.e
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        // Google Play services has no idea how to fix the issue
        // it rarely happens for the location service
    }
}

public void startTrack() {
    try {

        if (!getActivityRecognitionClient().isConnected() || !getActivityRecognitionClient().isConnecting() ) {

                Log.v(TAG, "getActivityRecognitionClient is not connected");                    
                getActivityRecognitionClient().connect();               

        }

}

public PendingIntent createPendingRequest() {
    if (null != mPendingIntent) {

    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServiceFour.class);
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 2, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
    return mPendingIntent;
}

/**
 * check googleplayservices is avaible or not
 * 
 * @return true if is avaible flase if not
 */
public boolean checkGooglePlayAvaible() {

    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    mIsRemove = false;
}

private ActivityRecognitionClient getActivityRecognitionClient() {
    if (mActivityRecognitionClient == null) {

        mActivityRecognitionClient = new ActivityRecognitionClient(getApplicationContext(), this, this);
    }
    return mActivityRecognitionClient;
}
```

So with it every 2 min User's Current Activity will be send to service four. in my service four(Intent service) :

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {
            ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);
            //
            if (result != null) {
                //
                Log.d("Aha", "he he");
            } else {
                Log.d("Ohno", "T_T");
            }

}
```

It work fine but when i uninstall app. and install again all ActivityRecognitionResult  in servicefour is null it just can be work fine again if i restart device. I don't know how to fix this . Please help me and thanks for reading.

Comment: Anything looking like a warning or an error? What about the logcat?

Comment: just this warning :01-09 17:02:09.510: W/ResourceType(18189): getEntry failing because entryIndex 27 is beyond type entryCount 3
01-09 17:02:09.510: W/ResourceType(18189): Failure getting entry for 0x7f05001b (t=4 e=27) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
01-09 17:02:09.510: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(18189): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
01-09 17:02:28.289: W/ResourceType(18189): getEntry failing because entryIndex 27 is beyond type entryCount 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post my code for Recognizing the User's Current Activity but with newest api .

```
public class GPSLocationService extends Service implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

private String TAG = "[ServiceDetect]";
//
private PendingIntent mActivityRecognitionPendingIntent;
// Stores the current instantiation of the activity recognition client
private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (checkGooglePlayAvaible()) {
        startTrack();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // -------------------------------------
    // to remove ActivityRecognition call
    // ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.removeActivityUpdates
    //----------------------------
    ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(mApiClient, 2 * 60 * 1000,
            createPendingRequest());
    //
    mApiClient.disconnect();
   stopSelf();


}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended");
    mApiClient.connect();
}

public void startTrack() {

    if (mApiClient == null) {
        mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext()).addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
    }
    if (!mApiClient.isConnected() || !mApiClient.isConnecting()) {

        mApiClient.connect();

    }

}

public PendingIntent createPendingRequest() {
    if (null != mActivityRecognitionPendingIntent) {

    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServiceFour.class);
        mActivityRecognitionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 2, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
    return mActivityRecognitionPendingIntent;
}

public boolean checkGooglePlayAvaible() {

    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

}
}
```

And now in my servicefour . I receive ActivityRecognitionResult  :

```
 @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {
            if (bundle.containsKey("com.google.android.location.internal.EXTRA_ACTIVITY_RESULT")) {
                String activityRecognitionResult = bundle
                        .getParcelable("com.google.android.location.internal.EXTRA_ACTIVITY_RESULT") + "";
                Log.d(TAG, "activityRecognitionResult " + activityRecognitionResult +" (^.,,.^)");                                  
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(18189): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

Your GooglePlayServices are not working.

Make sure you included them properly (post your Gradle files etc).

Comment: Thank you . I have checked it and updated google play services. But it didn't work. But i have found a stupid way to make it work